# Iterating duplicate xml elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I have an XML document like this:

```
  <author>someone</author> 
  <category>Severe Disruption - 5 hours</category> 
  <category>Roadworks</category>
  <pubDate>Sun, 23 Sep 2012 05:07:39 BST</pubDate>
```

And my existing code is this:

```
  _xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                highwaysResults.Items.Clear();
                foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
                {
                    highwaysFeedItem _item = new highwaysFeedItem();
                    _item.Title = value.Element("title").Value;
                    _item.Description =    Regex.Replace(value.Element("description").Value,
                    @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);
                    _item.PubDate = value.Element("pubDate").Value;
                    _item.Category = value.Element("category").Value;
                    _item.Category2 = value.Element("category").Value;

                        highwaysResults.Items.Add(_item);
```

The issue is, that my code only reads the first 'category' value, but the XML I am using now has two 'category' values.

I only want to read the second 'category' value. It would be bonus to read both but not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `value.Elements("category")` and iterate the items.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a good start and I worked at the rest -  I did it like this:
 _item.Category = value.Elements("category").ElementAt(0).Value;
                        _item.Category2 = value.Elements("category").ElementAt(1).Value;

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath: `using System.Xml.XPath;` you can select the second category element.

```
_item.Category2 = value.XPathSelectElement("category[2]").Value;
```